# jquery replaceWith implications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replacewith

I am using replaceWith  for `input type=file` to handle changes of the file the user wants to upload.

I have this code:

```
$('#add_cv_input').change(function() {
    // here is some code               
    else {
        alert('put one of this: pdf doc docx');
        $("#add_cv_input").replaceWith('<input id="add_cv_input" type="file"/>');
    }
});
```

now the problem is that this jquery changed event does not being called after the first time that the user had uploaded the wrong extension.

I don't have a clue why this is happening. Everything works fine if at the first time the user uploads a valid extension and then he changes it to other valid extension.

Answer (score 4):

When you destroy the first item, the event handler is destroyed with it.  If you want the event handler to be on the new item, you have two options:

1. You can reinstall the event handler on the new object after creating it.
2. You can use delegated event handling from a parent that is not destroyed.

It's probably easiest to use delegated event handling with the dynamic form of `.on()`:

```
$(some parent selector).on('change', '#add_cv_input', function() {
    // code here
});
```

Where you pick some parent selector that is as close as possible to `#add_cv_input`, but is not destroyed.

---

If you wanted to reattach the event handler after replacing the element, you could do so like this (though delegated event handling would be cleaner):

```
function processChange() {
    // here is some code               
    else {
        alert('put one of this: pdf doc docx');
        $("#add_cv_input").replaceWith('<input id="add_cv_input" type="file"/>');
        $('#add_cv_input').change(processChange);
    }
});

$('#add_cv_input').change(processChange);
```

Comment: How do I reinstall the event after destroying the element?

Comment: @VladIoffe - I added how to reinstall to my answer.

Comment: are you sure it is like this: $('#add_cv_input').change(processChange); and not like this: $('#add_cv_input').change(processChange());?

Comment: after changing it to $('#add_cv_input').change(processChange()); it is not working on opera, works fine on chrome and ie, any idea why?

Comment: @VladIoffe - I'm quite sure it's NOT `$('#add_cv_input').change(processChange())`.  That just calls `processChange()` immediately and passes it's return value to the `.change()` method.  That is not what you want.  `.change()` takes a function reference.  You'd have to suppply a working example (perhaps in a jsFiddle) that we could debug in Opera to know more about that.  The code is technically correct.

Answer (score 3):

You are destroying the original element which the event handler was bound to, which is why its not triggered again. Instead of replacing the element try to reset it.

Edit: Seeing as resetting the single file input is non-trivial(as `this.value = null;` doesn't work in all browsers), replacing the element seems to be the better option.

You can just attach the event handler to the the newly created element. [[`.replaceAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/)]

```
function cv_input_file(){
    // here is some code               
    else {
        alert('put one of this: pdf doc docx');
        $('<input id="add_cv_input" type="file"/>')
         .replaceAll("#add_cv_input")
         .change(cv_input_file);
    }
}
$('#add_cv_input').change(cv_input_file);
```

or use event delegation so you wouldn't have to add a handler every time you replace the element.

```
$(document/*or the closest static ancestor*/).on('change', '#add_cv_input', function() {
    // here is some code               
    else {
        alert('put one of this: pdf doc docx');
        $("#add_cv_input").replaceWith('<input id="add_cv_input" type="file"/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 This is a more feasible solution as all other information of the element does not need to be reapplied.

Comment: I don't want to reset all of the form, I want to rest only the input type=file element. How do I do that?

Comment: @VladIoffe try using `this.value = null;` instead of the replacement statement.

Comment: I will thanks, but is it changing also the file in the element and not only the path?

Comment: @VladIoffe I just tested it an dit doesn't work in IE or Opera, I guess replacing the element then re-attaching the event handler is the better option. See http://jsfiddle.net/etZcv/

Comment: This fiddle doesn't shows any replacement or re-attaching of the event.

Comment: @VladIoffe it demonstrates `this.value = null;`